# Is there a way to access tag search results by an URL?

Tags: support, tags, search

Since the results of a tag search are created dynamically, we are not directed to another page and we don't see any URL for the search results.

For example, I searched "java" in [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) page of Stack Overflow. Is there a way to access these search results by an URL?

[image]

Comment: Do you expect this: [`https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]) ?

Comment: No. My question is about searching tags, not tagged Q&As. @Arulkumar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

It will make an HTTP POST request via Ajax on keypress to the URL

> https://stackoverflow.com/filter/tags-for-index

[image]

Along with data

> filter=%tagname%&tab=Popular

The data is send via POST and you can't access it via URL.

If you try to navigate to the URL along with data, you will get a custom **404**

[image]